# SciChart: WPF 3D Line Chart

Tags: c#, wpf, scichart

I'm currently considering using SciChart, but have a question that I've not found the answer to.

Is it possible to create a  "3D line chart" in WPF C# that looks similar to this using SciChart?

[image: 3D LineChart]

Comment: What did SciChart reply when you ask them the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a PointLineRenderableSeries3D type in SciChart which provides lines in a 3-dimensional space.

[You can see examples here](https://www.scichart.com/example/wpf-3d-chart-example-simple-pointline-chart-3d/)

[and documentation here](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/v5.x/webframe.html#The%20PointLine%203D%20Chart%20Type.html)

[image]